# Ubuntu 20.04 lagging system

Tags: 20.04, cpu, ubuntu-gnome

I've just done an upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS on a Dell Latitude 7370. The UI and all applications are lagging/freezing for 2-3 seconds every 5-10 seconds. I had no such issues with 18.04. It seems this happens when gnome-s+ is using 50 to 90 %CPU. Below the different logs. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
top - 17:59:05 up 1 day,  1:32,  1 user,  load average: 0,76, 0,88, 1,57
Tâches: 241 total,   2 en cours, 239 en veille,   0 arrêté,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 17,6 ut,  1,1 sy,  0,0 ni, 81,0 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,3 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   7853,6 total,   2647,7 libr,   2096,1 util,   3109,8 tamp/cache
MiB Éch:    976,0 total,    976,0 libr,      0,0 util.   4721,7 dispo Mem 

    PID UTIL.     PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM    TEMPS+ COM.     
   2460 ubuntop+  20   0 4723020 322520 114568 R  67,9   4,0  42:02.04 gnome-s+ 
   2309 ubuntop+  20   0  937828 161780 108616 S   2,6   2,0  10:43.89 Xorg     
  10365 ubuntop+  20   0  966096  53264  40208 S   1,7   0,7   0:04.81 gnome-t+ 
   2246 ubuntop+  20   0   10952   8088   4116 S   0,7   0,1   0:11.41 dbus-da+ 
   4141 ubuntop+  20   0  781220 104100  53816 S   0,7   1,3   0:21.29 megasync 
   9661 ubuntop+  20   0 4086332 602808 262408 S   0,7   7,5   4:17.07 MainThr+ 
      1 root      20   0  168116  11952   8320 S   0,3   0,1   0:08.20 systemd  
   1085 message+  20   0   10304   6824   4088 S   0,3   0,1   0:06.62 dbus-da+ 
   2506 ubuntop+  20   0  162820   7624   6848 S   0,3   0,1   0:02.58 at-spi2+ 
   9734 ubuntop+  20   0 2671228 311604 250824 S   0,3   3,9   0:38.86 Web Con
```

free -h

```
total       utilisé      libre     partagé tamp/cache   disponible
Mem:          7,7Gi       2,1Gi       2,2Gi       1,1Gi       3,4Gi       4,2Gi
Partition d'échange:       975Mi          0B       975Mi
```

sysctl vm.swappiness `= 60`

ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 sep 30 11:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 sep 30 11:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 sep 30 11:27 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 sep 30 11:19 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 sep 30 11:19 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

sudo dmidecode -s bios-version `1.18.5`

sudo lshw -C memory

```
*-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       fabricant: Dell Inc.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       version: 1.18.5
       date: 10/08/2019
       taille: 64KiB
       capacité: 16MiB
       fonctionnalités: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       identifiant matériel: 3c
       emplacement: L1 Cache
       taille: 64KiB
       capacité: 64KiB
       fonctionnalités: synchronous internal write-back data
       configuration : level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L1 cache
       identifiant matériel: 3d
       emplacement: L1 Cache
       taille: 64KiB
       capacité: 64KiB
       fonctionnalités: synchronous internal write-back instruction
       configuration : level=1
  *-cache:2
       description: L2 cache
       identifiant matériel: 3e
       emplacement: L2 Cache
       taille: 512KiB
       capacité: 512KiB
       fonctionnalités: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration : level=2
  *-cache:3
       description: L3 cache
       identifiant matériel: 3f
       emplacement: L3 Cache
       taille: 4MiB
       capacité: 4MiB
       fonctionnalités: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration : level=3
  *-memory
       description: Mémoire Système
       identifiant matériel: 41
       emplacement: Carte mère
       taille: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM LPDDR3 Synchrone 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
          produit: 0
          fabricant: 0
          identifiant matériel: 0
          numéro de série: 0
          emplacement: System Board Memory
          taille: 4GiB
          bits: 64 bits
          horloge: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM LPDDR3 Synchrone 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
          produit: 0
          fabricant: 0
          identifiant matériel: 1
          numéro de série: 0
          emplacement: System Board Memory
          taille: 4GiB
          bits: 64 bits
          horloge: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
  *-memory NON-RÉCLAMÉ
       description: Memory controller
       produit: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
       fabricant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 1f.2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 21
       bits: 32 bits
       horloge: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       configuration : latency=0
       ressources : mémoire:dc32c000-dc32ffff
```

ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

```
ls: cannot access '/home/ubuntophe/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file
```

inxi -G

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 515 driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: i915 resolution: 3200x1800~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 515 (SKL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8
```

Comment: Hello!  This seems to be a problem I had  (each time I would install Ubuntu) It would lag and freeze, and took awhile to login, etc.  But (In my case) I solved it by apt updating & upgrading, and crucially:  Installing the latest graphics card's drivers. (And of course rebooted after that) Have you tried that?

Comment: Several time I have done apt- update and upgrade and reboot, and there is no additional drivers to be installed in "software and updates". The lagging is still happening.

Comment: Could you post the output of `inxi -G`? Copy the answer from the terminal and paste it into your question.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @kanehekili, `inxi -g` and `sudo inxi -g` gives nothing (command not found)

Comment: @heynnema thanks for your comments and answer `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` gives 'no such file`

Comment: @ubuntophe Go ahead and do the rest of my answer, as I suspect it'll solve your problem. Report back.

Comment: `sudo apt install inxi` will enable you to provide us with more data....

Comment: @heynnema thanks a lot for your prompt replies, I haven't been able yet to find the time to implement your solutions. I will certainly keep you posted on the outcome.

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the BIOS and the problem of lagging remains. Regarding the increase of the swapfile, I get this on step two: `rm: impossible to delete /swapfile: no such file or directory`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`.

Comment: @heynnema, here you go: `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0` nd one more thing, I've noticed that the lagging disappears after my computer get back on from sleeping mode. I don't know if that can help identify the issue.

Comment: I'm not well versed in LVM disks, esp if they're encrypted. Your current swap is way too small, and should be resized to 4G. You can search here for "lvm" for more help, or "man lvm" in the `terminal`. I've struck out the swap part of my answer. Sorry.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for getting back. I'm quite new with Linux and I'm not sure what you mean with LMV and what exactly should I be looking for? You mean I can't use your answer to increase the swap and should be looking for an other way? Thank in advance.

Comment: @kanehekili I've updated my question with the output for inxi -G. Any idea what is wrong? Thanks !

Comment: LVM (Logical Volume Manager) is a device mapper framework that provides logical volume management for the Linux kernel. Most modern Linux distributions are LVM-aware to the point of being able to have their root file systems on a logical volume. In `terminal` type `man lvm` and you'll see the commands available to manage your LVM disk partitions, and would be used to resize your swap volume to 4G. You can also search here on AU for "lvm" and probably get instructions on how to do that.

Comment: Since you are using an Intel card, drivers should be ok. Your 3D support is also given. I suspect the LVM then - since I'm not using it, I am out of ideas. I'd reinstall the new Ubuntu version, since I've had always problems with upgrading from one version to another....

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is **Megasync Client**. When the client is closed, it all goes back to normal and the system runs smoothly.

I don't know why, but when Megasync Client is open, and making the whole system lagging, it does not show an increase in CPU% usage in `top` for `Megasync` but for `gnome-s+`.

Sorry for being late in posting the solution and thank you all for your kind support.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the culprit was related to the **ibus daemon**. I've been long into understanding why ibus is causing this but I'm still empty on that regard.

In my case, ibus only starts causing issues after about 2 days of the PC running (minus sleeping time) regardless of me putting PC to sleep or not.